# React: State does not get updated after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm trying to do two AJAX calls in my React project and have my UI render according to the data received. This is my render method:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.examsLoaded) {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.openModal}>Details</Button>
                <Modal show={this.state.modalOpen} onHide={this.closeModal}>
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title>{this.props.course.name}</Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <DetailModalContent course={this.props.course} exams={this.exams} grades={this.grades}/>
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                        <Button onClick={this.closeModal}>Sluiten</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        )
    }
    else {
        return (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        )
    }
}
```

The render method checks if the AJAX data is available yet and if not, just renders a 'Loading...' message. This is the code that fetches the data:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/course/' + this.props.course.id + '/exams').then((examResp) => {
        examResp.json().then((examData) => {
            this.exams = examData;
            console.log('Course data fetched'); // THIS APPEARS


            fetch('http://localhost:8080/user/1/grades').then((gradeResponse) => { // THIS DATA IS FETCHED
                console.log('Done fetching grades'); // THIS APPEARS
                gradeResponse.json((gradeData) => {
                    console.log('Parsed JSON'); // Here is where it goes wrong. This no longer appears.
                    this.grades = gradeData;

                    this.setState({
                        examsLoaded: true,
                        modalOpen: false
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
},
```

The weird thing is, I used to only have 1 fetch method and everything would work fine. As soon as I called `setState` the component rerenders and the data is displayed. However, after adding the second one, it doesn't work anymore. See my `console.log`'s. Everything works fine 'till I parse the JSON, after that, nothing gets run anymore.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: On a side note, you should be saving your data in the component's state rather than directly as a prop (this.grades). Can you verify what the return value of the second ajax call is? Perhaps it's malformed?

Comment: @TMitchell Yeah I should indeed... I can verify that the data is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetch's json() method returns a promise. You are using it correctly in the first call, but the second call you are treating it as a function rather than a promise.

Try

```
gradeResponse.json().then((gradeData) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Argh basically just a typo then! So silly... Thank you so much ;)

Comment: @RoemerBakker no worries, sometimes the obvious things are the hardest to spot

Answer (score -1):

You need to write this logic inside componentDidUpdate. componentDidMount will be triggered only for the first time.

Please refer to the React [documentation.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html)

Probably you will need both componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch('http://localhost:8080/course/' + this.props.course.id + '/exams').then((examResp) => {
    examResp.json().then((examData) => {
        this.exams = examData;
        console.log('Course data fetched'); // THIS APPEARS
                this.setState({
                    examsLoaded: true
                }); //At this point some state is changed, so componentDidUpdate will be triggered. Then in that function below, grades will be fetched and state is changed, which should call render again.

    });
  });
},

    componentDidUpdate(){
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/user/1/grades').then((gradeResponse) => { // THIS DATA IS FETCHED
            console.log('Done fetching grades'); // THIS APPEARS
            gradeResponse.json((gradeData) => {
                console.log('Parsed JSON'); // Here is where it goes wrong. This no longer appears.
                this.grades = gradeData;

                this.setState({
                    examsLoaded: true,
                    modalOpen: false
                });
            });
        });

  }
```

Since I am not with react environment right now. Will update as soon as I try.

Comment: So I should be able to leave the render method intact and rename `componentDidMount` to `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: @Amit Teli what you're saying is true. But the ajax calls in componentDidMount are asynchronous and both resolve as part of the first invocation, so it could remain where is it.

Comment: @TMitchell So what should I do? They don't work where they are right now.

Comment: @TMitchell, What I think is, both the ajax call will go through and setState would be called. But now there is no scope that the render would be called again.

Comment: @TMitchell They do go through indeed. But after `json()` nothing happens anymore, not even `console.log`'s. The scope is still available after the first `json()`. How is that possible?